# SelectedItem unknown DataContext although datacontext is set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I have a `ListBox` with a static `ObservableCollection<HUDInfo>` is bound. The `DataTrigger` shows the following error "PropertyPath | Cannot resolve property 'StatusConnection' in data context of type 'my window class'".

```
                    <ListBox 
                        x:Name="ListBoxAvailableHuDs" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableHUDs, Source={x:Static Core:HudModel.Current}}"
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusConnection}" Value="CanDisconnect">
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListBox>
```

On the `Window` I set the following `DataContext`:

`DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

My `TextBlock` also can not resolve the `DataContext`

```
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="{Binding SelectedItem.DeviceId, ElementName=ListBoxAvailableHuDs}"/>
```

"Cannot resolve property 'DeviceId' in data context of type 'object'"

How to set the `DataContext` of the `ListBox` to `HudInfo` or that the `ListBoxItem` is using the right `DataContext`?

Comment: The Window's (or the ListBox's) DataContext is irrelevant when you've explicitly set the Source of the ItemsSource Binding. The DataContext of a ListBoxItem is the respective element from the AvailableHUDs collection. `StatusConnection` and `DeviceId` must be public properties in class `HUDInfo`.

Comment: Sure when the app is compiled and started, everything works, but only at design time there are these errors that I want to solve.

Comment: Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Restart does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime the data context is resolved correctly for each list box item, however, the designer is not able to do this.  You may be able to do the following:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance HudInfo }">
    <Style.Triggers>
    ...
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance HudInfo">
```

with

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

I find this can cause an error to be shown in the designer - underlining the d:DataContext part, but it at least allows it to resolve the bindings.

Comment: the error is "the datacontext-property is no found in the namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008'". But the binding problem with the TextBlock ({Binding SelectedItem.DeviceId, ElementName = ListBoxAvailableHuDs}) can not be solved.

Comment: I've updated my answer - put d:DataContext on the Style - not sure this will solve the issue in your comment though - give it a go